# Using ParseDelegator to find the first occurrence of /wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system in input or its children

Tags: java, html-parsing, wikipedia

When inputting for example Linux, it will look for the first instance of /wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system, if it isn't found, it will look at its direct children to find it.

My expected output is

> Searching: Linux - Wikipedia
> Checking children:
> Found in: Bell Labs - Wikipedia

I'm not printing the second line because I think it is recursively going through the children without going back to main. How do I loop back to main before checking my children so that it goes through my if statement?

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        String subject = args[0].replace(" ", "_");
        System.out.println("Searching: " + subject + " - Wikipedia");

        URL url = new URL("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + subject);

        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String input;
            while ((input = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(input);
            }
            in.close();

            ParserDelegator parser = new ParserDelegator();
            MyParserCallback callback = new MyParserCallback();
            parser.parse(new StringReader(sb.toString()), callback, true);

            if (!callback.hasFound()) {
                System.out.println("Checking children:");

                Set<String> visitedLinks = new HashSet<>();
                visitedLinks.add("/wiki/" + subject);

                for (String href : callback.visitedLinks) {
                    if (!visitedLinks.contains(href)) {
                        visitedLinks.add(href);

                        String childUrl = "https://en.wikipedia.org" + href;
                        BufferedReader childIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new URL(childUrl).openStream()));
                        StringBuilder childSb = new StringBuilder();
                        while ((input = childIn.readLine()) != null) {
                            childSb.append(input);
                        }
                        childIn.close();

                        ParserDelegator childParser = new ParserDelegator();
                        MyParserCallback childCallback = new MyParserCallback();
                        childParser.parse(new StringReader(childSb.toString()), childCallback, true);

                        if (childCallback.hasFound()) {
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question.

Comment: I added a question